# Hilt-Dagger ViewModel calling from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm using the `ViewModel` to update the title in the action bar

SharedViewModel

```
class SharedViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    val title: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }

    val backButton: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    }
}
```

MainActivity observer

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
...
sharedViewModel.title.observe(this, Observer {
    supportActionBar?.title = it
})
```

Using the code below seems to create a new instance in `Fragment` (checked in the debugger):

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
...
private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
```

But seems to work this way

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

[Article reference](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack)

Is this supposed to be done this way or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a shared view model in a fragment you have to use `by activityViewModels()` instead of `by viewModels()`.

Why does the next line work but `by viewModels()` doesn't?

```
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Because by default `viewModels()` has its `ownerProducer` argument value as `{ this }`. To understand it better here is the source code:

```
@MainThread
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.viewModels(
    noinline ownerProducer: () -> ViewModelStoreOwner = { this },
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> Factory)? = null
) = createViewModelLazy(VM::class, { ownerProducer().viewModelStore }, factoryProducer)
```

As you can see it is an extension function for `Fragment` class. It means that the  `ViewModelStoreOwner` is the **fragment**. As soon as the fragment is removed from the stack all view models it stores in view model store are gone.

But if you use `by activityViewModels()` you use `Activity` as view model store owner. Notice use of `requireActivity().viewModelStore` instead of `ownerProducer().viewModelStore` which is a `Fragment` by default.

```
@MainThread
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.activityViewModels(
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> Factory)? = null
) = createViewModelLazy(VM::class, { requireActivity().viewModelStore },
    factoryProducer ?: { requireActivity().defaultViewModelProviderFactory })
```

Eventually, `createViewModelLazy` is calling

```
ViewModelProvider(store, factory).get(viewModelClass.java)
```

which is the equivalent of you creating view model by hand using

```
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

#### How to fix the issue?

Use `by activityViewModels()`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
...
private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Note: `by activityViewModels()` and `by viewModels()` are just lazy load implementations of the `ViewModelProvider(...).get(...)`.